# Usuario ao logar tem 2 tipos de menus e antes disso o sistema deve entender se ele esta logado ou não para exibir um o outro menu

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, login

Pessoal no meu código acima, estou tentando exibir 2 tipos de menu para o usuário, quando logado, e não logado, no caso quando logado ele ainda monta mais um outro menu comparando qual tipo de usuário esta logado, se e um usuário simples ou usuário avançado... só que esse meu echo ta com problema não estou conseguindo fazer exibir um ou outro na condição... alguém poderia me ajudar?

Detalhe Desenhado abaixo :

LOGIN | CADASTRO

QUANDO CARA CLICA EM UM DELES VAI APARECER UMA ABA FLUTUANTE ABAIXO..

SE CASO O CARA LOGAR , LOGIN e CADASTRO DESAPARECE | e EXIBE NOME DO USUARIO CADASTRADO NO SISTEMA; FICANDO ASSIM

USUARIO 
e abaixo os links dos menus para aquele usuario.

, mas ao logar, o sistema vai identificar qual usuario vai ter acesso a qual menu...
pois no sistema abaixo preciso que seja mostrado o menu correto para o usuario a condição ja funciona perfeitamente, o problema e que preciso fazer um if else, para exibir somente os menus de logado e o não logado já ate pus dentro de cada echo...

```
 <div class="auth auth--header">
          <ul class="auth__nav">
           <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usertype']))
{
echo '<li class="dropdown auth__nav-item">
              <div class="dropdown__menu auth__dropdown--restore">
                <!-- BEGIN AUTH RESTORE-->
                <h5 class="auth__title">Resetar Senha</h5>
                <form action="#" class="auth__form js-restore-form js-parsley">
                  <div class="auth__row form-group">
                    <label for="restore-email-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Digite usuario ou email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="restore-email-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row">
                    <button type="submit" class="auth__in auth__in--submit">Resetar senha</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row"><span class="auth__links">Back para
                      <button type="button" class="js-user-login">Logar em</button>ou
                      <button type="button" class="js-user-register">Registrar</button></span>
                    <!-- end of block .auth__links-->
                  </div>
                </form>
                <!-- end of block .auth__form-->
                <!-- END AUTH RESTORE-->
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown auth__nav-item">
              <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle js-auth-nav-btn auth__nav-btn">
                <svg class="auth__icon-user">
                  <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                </svg><span class="header__span"> Entrar /</span>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown__menu auth__dropdown--login">
                <!-- BEGIN AUTH LOGIN-->
                <h5 class="auth__title">Entre com sua conta</h5>
                <form action="#" class="auth__form js-login-form js-parsley">
                  <div class="auth__row form-group">
                    <label for="login-username-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="login-username-dropdown" required data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-validation-threshold="5" data-parsley-minlength-message="Login should be at least 6 chars" class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row auth__row--password form-group">
                    <label for="login-password-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="login-password-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row">
                    <button type="button" class="auth__forgot js-user-restore">Perdeu a senha ?</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="auth__in auth__in--submit">Entrar?</button><span class="auth__remember">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="remember-in-dropdown" class="in-checkbox">
                      <label for="remember-in-dropdown" class="in-label">Lembre-me</label></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row"><span class="auth__links">Não e usuário?
                      <button type="button" class="js-user-register">Pegue uma conta</button></span></div>
                </form>
                <!-- end of block .auth__form-->
                <!-- END AUTH LOGIN-->
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown auth__nav-item">
              <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle auth__nav-btn"><span class="header__span">Cadastrar</span></button>
              <div class="dropdown__menu auth__dropdown--register">
                <!-- BEGIN AUTH REGISTER-->
                <h5 class="auth__title">Registre uma nova conta</h5>
                <form action="#" class="auth__form js-register-form js-parsley">
                  <div class="auth__coll form-group">
                    <label for="register-name-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="register-name-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__coll auth__coll--right form-group">
                    <label for="register-lastname-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Sobre Nome</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="register-lastname-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__coll auth__coll--email form-group">
                    <label for="register-email-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="register-email-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__coll auth__coll--right form-group">
                    <label for="register-password-dropdown" class="auth__label control-label">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="register-password-dropdown" required class="auth__in auth__in--text form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="auth__row"><span class="auth__links">Back para
                      <button type="button" class="js-user-login">Entrar</button></span>
                    <button type="submit" class="auth__in auth__in--submit">Entrar</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div>
             </li>    ';
}
else
{
echo '  <li class="dropdown auth__nav-item">
              <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle js-auth-nav-btn auth__nav-btn">
                <svg class="auth__icon-user">
                  <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                </svg><span class="header__span"> <?php if (isset($username)){echo $username;} ?><?php if (isset($model)){echo $model;} ?></span>
              </button>
        <div class="dropdown__menu auth__dropdown--login">
           <nav class="worker__nav">
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="height:10px;line-height:10px;"><span></span></a>
    <div class="submenu" style="width:92px;">
      <?php if($username) {

    echo '<li><a href="cp/chatusers/index.php">Minha Conta</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatusers/favorites.php">Favoritos</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatusers/updateprofile.php">Meu Perfil</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatusers/viewsessions.php">Hist&oacute;rico</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatusers/buyminutes.php">Dinheiro</a></li>

    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';} ?>
    <?php if($model) {

    echo '<li><a href="index.php">Minha Conta</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatmodels/broadcast.php">Transmiss&aatilde;o</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatmodels/updateprofile.php">Meu Perfil</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatmodels/showslist.php">Hist&oacute;rico</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatmodels/uploadpicture.php">Minhas Fotos</a></li>

    <li><a href="cp/chatmodels/paymentop.php">Dinheiro</a></li>

    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';} ?>


    </div>   
</li>
</nav>';
}
?>


            </ul>
          <!-- end of block .auth header-->
        </div>
```

Comment: De onde vem as variaveis $model e $username? Provavelmente o erro é ai.

Comment: Não na verdade o erro ta vindo do '' echo... não sei como colocar 2 echos um dentro do outro e fazer uma condição comparatoria... $model e $username ja pega as variaveis do banco de dados...

Comment: Mas qual echo vem o erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, você vai ter apresentar o menu conforme as permissões que o usuário tiver através de if
Tipo

```html
<?php if($_SESSION[ 'permissao']=="Nivel1" ]){ ?>
  <li>Mostrar Tag do menu ADM</li>
<?php }else if($_SESSION[ 'permissao']=="Nivel2" ){ ?>
  <li>Mostrar tag do menu referente a esta permissao</li>
<?php} ?>
```

Comment: mas ai chamo a sessão ali e dispenso o q ja fiz? não entendi...

Comment: No codigo la acho que você não entendeu,

Comment: No conteudo do codigo esta explicito, 

ele verifica se ja esta logado ou não e nisso, ele oculta e exibe as divs necessarias, so que dentro dessa verificação de divs, ele verifica se o usuário e um ou outro para exibir um outro tipo de Lista... não tem nada a ver com que o Amigo acima postou ai!